# Is there any system level security analyzers for Linux distro configuration?

Tags: security

First of all this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292861/is-there-any-configuration-validator-for-linux).

What I'm asking for is an application agnostic security analyzer for a particular or all major Linux distributions. What it should do are the following:

- check any unused port are opened (if some particular service is listening on a particular port it's OK)
- make sure configuration files permissions for any main stream services in use are OK (e.g. `setgid` for `bind` configuration files etc.)
- various OS hardening aspects: ssl keys are in the same folder (i.e. `/etc/certs/`) with right permissions, mount flags for `/tmp` and other partitions posses no or minimal threats, processes are bind to `localhost`, `ssh` is configured correctly (pass login disabled, root login disabled) etc.
- monitoring configuration: `root` mail is forwarded to some other user, logs are stored/forwarded securely etc.

The purpose of a such tool would be validation of a freshly build `packer` AWS AMI or `virtualbox` image.

So what I'm looking for is a some kind of dynamic operating system configuration analyzer to make sure provisioning was done right and the base box used was not flawed security-wise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's an "unused open port"?

Comment: You mean something like Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer, just for Linux? The Center for Internet Security (CIS) provides the CAT tool to its members ($$$!) that automates the validation against their benchmarks. However, your requirements appear somewhat special, so I doubt you will find a tool that matches exactly what you asked for.

Comment: what are the "major Linux distributions" in scope?

Comment: @JeffSchaller the service that should listen on this port is down but firewall keeps this port opened. It could cause some trouble if the service would up at some point by somebody while being not properly configured leaving security hole. Yep, the way I named it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Are you looking something like [AppArmour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)

Comment: @countermode yep, something similar but open-source and free to incorporate it into the ops pipeline.

Comment: if the service is down, the port is "closed", though it may not be *firewalled*

Comment: @JeffSchaller Debian, Ubuntu, RHAL, SLES

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, but at some point the service may be started manually. It will then listen on an open port (as it was not explicitly closed by a firewall).

Comment: [Here](https://cisofy.com/lynis/)'s one I just stumbled upon a few days ago.  There are many others, if you can be bothered to search for them (just not here, the question is too broad for [unix.se]).

Comment: @SatoKatsura yep it's the one tool suggested in an accepted answer. And while the question is indeed seems to be quite broad IMO it's a relevant one as it directly touches issues that arise for DevOps specialists dealing with nix systems. And there is at least one answer matching a criteria so it's not *that* broad question after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) is a generic Linux security checker written as collection of shell scripts; it is free (GPLed) and it is designed to be extensible by site admins, so that might be the best match for what you seek for.

Comment: It looks quite similar to what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research in the same direction as the accepted answer I found one more option that might be a good choice to integrate into provision pipeline using Ansible/Chef/Puppet.

[dev-sec](http://dev-sec.io/) provides ready-made Ansible playbooks (as well as Chef cookbooks and Puppet manifests) to make sure operating system complies with various security standards (NIST, ISO etc.).

The good thing about this solution is that it fixes configuration issues. The bad thing - it could be something you don't want to disable or configure in that particular way.